# Number Picker Resets to MinValue While Scrolling

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have this Number Picker to select number from -10 to 10.
I use formatter to display from -10 to 10.

I want this number picker to start from 0, This was already done,
 but when I scroll the number picker will jump from 0 to -10, something like this

[image]

I use this following code

```
    final int min = -10;
    final int max = 10;

    final NumberPicker numberPicker = mView.findViewById(R.id.np_number_picker);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(max - min);
    numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    numberPicker.setValue(numberPicker.getValue() - min);

    numberPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
        @Override
        public String format(int i) {
            return Integer.toString(i + min);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your setMinValue to -10
i.e numberPicker.setMinValue(-10);